# Angular 4 optional application modul loading

Tags: angular

I'am stuck with a problem, I want to make an Angular project where is a base dashboard code and about 10 modules.

But when I sell the app, the costumers can select which modules they need so they only use what they paid for.

So I want something where I only modify one file to load only the specific modules and build that without editing the sidebar with new menu elements.

Is there anything that can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your are taking about subscription. If yes then you all need is that `AuthGuard` and `routes` which control all the route.

go to the official website for more details about it https://angular.io/guide/router

simply use `canActivate` to write your logic to prevent users from accessing the module which they have not subscribed